# ServiceMix / Fuse ESB + CXF dOSGi

Tags: cxf, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb, dosgi

How can I enable dOSGi in ServiceMix / Fuse ESB? I am thinking about [CXF dOSGi](http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi.html) here.

I tried to follow this answer: [Servicemix 4, DOSGi, and Zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481177/servicemix-4-dosgi-and-zookeeper), but when I hot-deploy proper versions of jars (from multi-bundle distribution) and [sample Greeter app](http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi-greeter-demo-walkthrough.html), I got error stating no SOAP binding is found.

I know I can choose framework in ServiceMix: Felix or Equinox so theoretically I could apply same instructions as to Felix configuration, but this wont work for me. ServiceMix is so much more complex than empty Felix container.

If CXF dOSGi doesn't work here, which other dOSGi distribution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend not using CXF - if you haven't encountered any peculiarities yet (i.e. bugs), you will soon enough.  (IMO using webservices for Java-to-Java communication == fail)

[Eclipse Communication Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/) (ECF) should work with any OSGi framework.  Another option is to look at [FuseSource Fabric](http://fabric.fusesource.org/), [Guillaume Nodet's blog](http://gnodet.blogspot.com/2011/06/distributed-osgi-in-fabric.html) has some info on dOSGi in Fabric.

Comment: ECF runs fine in ServiceMix. Just had to change container type to Equinox.